# error when retrive data from database Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

```js
var response = {};
var sticky = []

email = req.session.u_email;

var query = "select * from share_item where share_to=?  and status=?";
con.query(query, [email, 1], function(err, results) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    /*return void res.json({'status':false,"message":"somthing went wrong",'redirect':false});  */
  } else if (results.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var query = "select * from sticky where id = ?";
      con.query(query, [results[i].item_id], function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else if (result.length > 0) {
          for (j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
            var note = {
              id: result[j].id,
              des: result[j].description,
            }
            sticky.push(note)
          }
        }
        return void res.json(response)
      })
    }
  }
});
```

> Am getting error like Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. in express js I need the data from to tables with result of [i] what will be the solution for that

Comment: Please include the entire function and format your code.

Comment: you send the response twice (or more).. you need to check how many times you do `res.json` for the same request